# In Windows 10 How To Keep Password Prompt From Appearing On Sleep?

Tags: windows-10

I can't find the option in windows 10 to have my computer not prompt for a password when it comes out of sleep. Please point me a that, screen shot would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Click the Start Start menu and select Settings.
- Select Accounts.
- Click Sign-in options.

You should see something like this...
[image]

- Click the drop down menu under "Require sign-in" and select Never.

Let me know if that works for you.